# Difference between just reshaping and reshaping and getting transpose?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm currently studying CS231 assignments and I've realized something confusing. When calculating gradients, when I first reshape x then get transpose I got the correct result.

```
x_r=x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1)
dw= x_r.T.dot(dout)
```

[image]

However, when I reshape directly as the X.T shape it doesn't return the correct result.

```
dw = x.reshape(-1,x.shape[0]).dot(dout)
```

[image]

Can someone explain the following question?

How does the order of getting elements with np.reshape() change?
How reshaping (N,d1,d2..dn) shaped array into N,D array differs from getting a reshaped array of (D,N) with its transpose.

Comment: Test with a small `x` and look at the results from each step.  The `dot` step hides a lot details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While both your approaches result in arrays of same shape, there will by a difference in the order of elements due to the way numpy reads / writes elements. By default, `reshape` uses a C-like index order, which means the elements are read / written with the last axis index changing fastest, back to the first axis index changing slowest (taken from the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape)).

Here is an example of what that means in practice. Let's assume the following array `x`:

```py
x = np.asarray([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]])

print(x.shape) # (2, 3, 2)

print(x)
# output
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 3  4]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 7  8]
  [ 9 10]
  [11 12]]]
```

Now let's reshape this array the following two ways:

```py
opt1 = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
opt2 = x.reshape(-1, x.shape[0])

print(opt1.shape) # outptu: (2, 6)
print(opt2.shape) # output: (6, 2)

print(opt1)
# output:
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]]

print(opt2)
# output:
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]]
```

`reshape` first inferred the shape of the new arrays  and then returned a view where it read the elements in C-like index order.

To exemplify this on `opt1`: since the original array `x` has 12 elements, it inferred that the new array `opt1` must have a shape of `(2, 6)` (because 2*6=12). Now, `reshape` returns a view where:

```py
opt1[0][0] == x[0][0][0] 
opt1[0][1] == x[0][0][1]
opt1[0][2] == x[0][1][0]
opt1[0][3] == x[0][1][1]
opt1[0][4] == x[0][2][0]
opt1[0][5] == x[0][2][1]
opt1[1][0] == x[1][0][0]
...
opt1[1][5] == x[1][2][1]
```

So as described above, the last axis index changes fastest and the first axis index slowest. In the same way, the output for `opt2` will be computed.

You can now verify that transposing the first option will result in the same shape but a different order of elements:

```py
opt1 = opt1.T

print(opt1.shape) # output: (6, 2)

print(opt1)
# output: 
[[ 1  7]
 [ 2  8]
 [ 3  9]
 [ 4 10]
 [ 5 11]
 [ 6 12]]
```

Obviously, the two approaches do not result in the same array due to element ordering, even though they will have the same shape.

Comment: Thanks this answers my question but can you also explain how numpy executes this reshaping, why does it differ, what's C-like index order?

Comment: `reshape` where possible is just a `view`.  It works with the same data-buffer, but with a new `shape` and `strides`. `transpose` is also a view, but with a different `strides`.  The beginner's guide discusses some of this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#transposing-and-reshaping-a-matrix (though without as much reference to `strides` as I'd like).

Comment: @HakanAkgün I edited the answer to show how you can tell where which element will end up after reshaping in C-like index order. If you want know more about these things in general, I can recommend reading through [NumPy internals](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/internals.html#numpy-internals).